# Does a "gesundheit" for coughing exist?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

To wish someone good health (or just to be polite) after they sneeze we say "gesundheit".

Is there any word or phrase to say after someone coughs?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/304248/is-there-an-equivalent-of-bless-you-for-coughing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no word or phrase that is commonly said after someone coughs.

Comment: I hope this becomes the most-upvoted answer in ELL history.

Comment: "*Tissue*?..." I am hoping this became the most-upvoted comment in ELL history. lol